# A good hashing function for a non-uniform sequence of uniformly distributed 4 bits values?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have a very specific problem:

I have uniformly random values spread on a 15x50 grid and the sample I want to hash corresponds to a square of 5x5 cells centered around any possible grid position.

The number of samples can thus vary from 25 (away from borders, most cases) to 20, 15 (near a border) down to a minimum of 9 (in a corner).

So even though the cell values are random, the location introduces a deterministic variation in the sequence length.

The hash table size is a small number, typically between 50 and 20.

The function will operate on a large set of randomly generated grids (a few hundreds/thousands), and might be called a few thousands times per grid. The positions on the grid can be considered random.

I would like a function that could spread the 15x50 possible samples as evenly as possible.

I have tried the following pseudo-code:

```
int32 hash = 0;
int i = 0; // I guess i could take any initial value and even be left uninitialized, but fixing one makes the function deterministic
foreach (value in block)
{
    hash ^= (value << (i%28))
    i++
}
hash %= table_size
```

but the results, though not grossly imbalanced, do not seem very smooth to me. Maybe it's because the sample is too small, but the circumstances make it difficult to run the code on a bigger sample, and I would rather not have to write a complete test harness if some computer savvy has an answer ready for me :).

I am not sure pairing the values two by two and using a general purpose byte hashing strategy would be the best solution, especially since the number of values might be odd.

I have tought of using a 17th value to represent off-grid cells, but that seems to introduce a bias (the sequences from cells near a border will have a lot of "off grid" values).

I am not sure either what would be the best way to test the efficiency of various solutions (how many grids shall I generate to have an idea of the performances, for instance).

Comment: If these values really are uniformly distributed (and independent), you don't need a hash.  Just take the first (or last, or any) eight 4-bit values, interpret them as a single unsigned 32-bit integer, and reduce modulo the table size.

Comment: NOTE: `i` is unintialised. NOTE2: everything goes. But: shift, don't modulo, except at the end.

Comment: @wildplasser actually i might be random at the start, since it will be constrained to [0..27] by the modulo, but initializing it would make the function deterministic (and I simply forgot to do it :)). As for the modulo, you're right, but I find the modulo a bit more readable. I'm not interested in performances as much as in homogeneity.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I really don't think so. Taking the first 4 letters of a randomly generated string does not look like a perfect hash method to me.

Comment: For a longer string: mix the bits. Take care that the firste items are not dropped off at the left side. Eventually, **any* input bit must have the same influence of the outconme. The starting characters must still influence the result. And: test&measure, {wash,rinse,repeat}

Comment: @wildplasser well I'm aware of the basics, but producing the proper sequence of shifts for optimizing the avalanche effect or whatever is way beyond my maths. I was hoping someone had already worked out a solution for this unusual bit length (or was fluent in maths *and* kind enough to create one for me :)).

Comment: If you seek a hash function for sequences/_blocks_ of four bit values rather than for each four bit value, please say so in the title and near the beginning of the question. Do randomness tests, if they suggest the sequence of hash values might well come from a uniform random source, that's as good as it gets. There's no getting _evenly spread_ for _random_ input. Please substantiate `the results … do not seem very smooth to me`.

Comment: To extend on the comment by @Ilmari-Karonen: just be sure that the number of nybbles exploited is not small, or makes up for a number slightly below 100^n.

Comment: Perhaps this is what greybeard is getting at, but here's a quick experiment to try. Compute a histogram of uniform random (well, cryptographic quality pseudorandom) numbers between 0 inclusive and the table size exclusive. Is that even enough for you?

Comment: @greybeard you're absolutely right. I've edited the title. The data come from [this computer challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44707/lab-rat-race-an-exercise-in-genetic-algorithms). The grid is designed so that each color is equiprobable, but a given "lab rat" will only explore a subset of cells. The hash is meant to spread as evenly as possible a choice of behaviour depending on the lab rat's surroundings (which might be 25 cells or less if near a border). I have tested my function by hashing the surroundings from all possible locations, and observed a 3 to 1 variation.

Comment: @kuroineko: I haven't read the linked challenge, but if the distribution really is uniform then Ilmari Karonen's solution can't be beaten (in randomness, or obviously in computational effort) -- and if it *isn't* really uniform, then you should change your question.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You're right: I was not specific enough. Hopefully the edited version should make the catch (if there is one) more apparent.

Comment: (From your edits I gather the single values may be uniformly random but the sequences are anything but independent.) While hash functions and their domain is a deserving subject in its own right, this might be a case of trying to solve _a_ and asking for _b_: will the coordinates/sequences refer to one invariant array, or will there be a reference array queried with a huge number of hash-codes from many other arrays? How many accesses will occur so as to worry about distribution?

Comment: @greybeard Positions represent the location of a specimen of the genetic algorithm, which start on the left of the grid and tries to reach the right side. The hash is used to associate a behaviour parameter to a given grid location, so the idea is to  have the hash function group grid cells in evenly spread "buckets" corresponding each to a given set of behaviour parameters. The simulation runs many times, with a random grid generated each time, and a grid can be queried thousands of times during a specific run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite your scepticism I would just shove them through a standard hash function.
If they are well randomised (and relatively independent - you don't say) to begin with you probably don't need to do too much work. Fowler-Noll-Vo (FNV) is a good candidate in these circumstances.

FNV operates on a series of 8-bit input and your input is (logically) 4-bit.
I would start without even bothering to pack 'two by two' as you describe. 
If you feel like trying that, just logically pad odd length series with the message length (reduced to a 4 bit value obviously).

I wouldn't expect that packing to improve the hash. It may save you a tiny number of cycles because it swaps a relatively expensive `*` with a `<<` and a `|`.

Try both and report back!

Here are implementations of packed and 'normal' versions of FNV1a in C:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

static const uint32_t sFNVOffsetBasis=2166136261;
static const uint32_t sFNVPrime= 16777619;

const uint32_t FNV1aPacked4Bit(const uint8_t*const pBytes,const size_t pSize) {
    uint32_t rHash=sFNVOffsetBasis;
    for(size_t i=0;i<pSize;i+=2){
        rHash=rHash^(pBytes[i]|(pBytes[i+1]<<4));
        rHash=rHash*sFNVPrime;
    }
    if(pSize%2){//Length is odd. The loop missed the last element.
        rHash=rHash^(pBytes[pSize-1]|((pSize&0x1E)<<3));
        rHash=rHash*sFNVPrime;

    }
    return rHash;
}

const uint32_t FNV1a(const uint8_t*const pBytes,const size_t pSize) {
    uint32_t rHash=sFNVOffsetBasis;
    for(size_t i=0;i<pSize;++i){
        rHash=(rHash^pBytes[i])*sFNVPrime;
    } 
    return rHash;
}
```

NB: I've edited it to skip the first bit when adding in the length. Obviously the bottom bit of an odd length is 100% biased to 1. I don't know how length is distributed. It may be wiser to put it in at the start than the end.

Comment: Or even _Fowler-Noll-Vo_.

Comment: @greybeard. Or that too! I appear to have made a hash of my hash ;).

Comment: Though none solved my problem entirely, I reckon all 3 answers are to the point and useful, so I will base bounty attribution on the poster's reputation. Lucky you. And my thanks.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/

Here are few different hash function from experts on various fields. Functions are designed for 8bit values, but I am sure you can extend for your case. I dont know what to suggest, but I think that any of them should work better than your current idea.

Problem with current approach you propose is that values are cyclic in field 2^n and if you make mod 64 at the end for example you lost most values out and only last 3 values remains in final result.

Comment: That's a neat and useful page you linked there. No answer adressed my particular problem directly, but they were all useful, so the bounty went to the poster with the lowest reputation score. Thanks for your help.